# S3 to Redshift : Copy with Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, vpc

We previously used to copy files from s3 to Redshift using the COPY command every day, from a bucket with no specific policy.

```
COPY schema.table_staging     
FROM 's3://our-bucket/X/YYYY/MM/DD/'     
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxx'     
CSV     
GZIP     
DELIMITER AS '|'     
TIMEFORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

As we needed to improve the security of our S3 bucket, we added a policy to authorize connections either from our VPC (the one we use for our Redshift cluster) or specific IP address.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "S3PolicyId1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyAllExcept",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::our-bucket/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::our-bucket"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
                "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-123456789"
            },
            "NotIpAddressIfExists": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "12.35.56.78/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

This policy works well for accessing files from EC2, EMR or our specific address using AWS CLI or the boto Python library.

Here is the error we have on Redshift :

```
ERROR: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid xxxxxx,CanRetry 1
Détail : 
-----------------------------------------------
error:  S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,Rid xxxxxx,CanRetry 1
code:      8001
context:   Listing bucket=our-bucket prefix=X/YYYY/MM/DD/
query:     1587954
location:  s3_utility.cpp:552
process:   padbmaster [pid=21214]
-----------------------------------------------
```

Many thanks in advance if you can help us on this,

Damien

ps : this question is quite similar to this one : [Copying data from S3 to Redshift - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36398734/copying-data-from-s3-to-redshift-access-denied/40523899?noredirect=1#comment68288222_40523899)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'Enhanced VPC Routing' feature of Redshift. From the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-routing.html):

1. > When you use Amazon Redshift Enhanced VPC Routing, Amazon Redshift forces all COPY and UNLOAD traffic between your cluster and your data repositories through your Amazon VPC.
2. > If Enhanced VPC Routing is not enabled, Amazon Redshift routes traffic *through the Internet*, including traffic to other services within the AWS network.
3. > For traffic to an Amazon S3 bucket in the same region as your cluster, you can create a VPC endpoint to direct traffic directly to the bucket.