# Redshift cross-account manifest COPY with instance credentials failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I am trying to run a COPY command on my Redshift cluster in account-A that loads files from account-B's bucket:

```
COPY inventory FROM 's3://account-A-bucket/redshiftManifest' IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::account-A:role/readS3Role' DELIMITER ',' REGION 'us-west-2' MANIFEST GZIP COMPUPDATE OFF REMOVEQUOTES
```

the readS3Role has the permission:

```
{
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::account-A-bucket*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::account-B-bucket*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
```

s3://account-A-bucket/redshiftManifest is a list of files in account-B-bucket. account-B-bucket has the policy:

```
 {
        "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-A:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:Get*",
            "s3:List*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::account-B-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::account-B-bucket/*"
        ]
    }
```

I also added account-A on account-B-bucket's Access Control List.

As per [S3 to Redshift : Copy with Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40524700/s3-to-redshift-copy-with-access-denied), I enabled Enhanced VPC routing and it appears that my cluster's subnet has an Endpoint for com.amazonaws.us-west-2.s3 associated with it.

However, I am still getting S3ServiceException:Access Denied when Redshift attempts to load one of the files in account-B-bucket that is defined in the manifest.

Answer (score 3):

There was no need to enable Enhanced VPC Routing -- the `Access Denied` error says that you reached S3 just fine, but your permissions were insufficient.

Account A is not entitled to grant access to anything in Account B, so your `readS3Role` role should not be referring to Bucket-B.

The Bucket Policy on Bucket-B should grant access to `arn:aws:iam::account-A:role/readS3Role` (not `root`).

This way, the Redshift cluster will use `readS3Role` in Account-A to access Bucket-B.

Answer (score 2):

Issue ended up being that although I had a valid bucket policy, the objects in the S3 bucket were put their by a third account, and therefore could  not be accessed from my account.

I will have to use AWS credentials directly in my COPY to access the resources from Redshift